# "Can't truncate this stream" при очистке файла

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $fp = fopen("http://bukvochka.webatu.com/Litra/Library/9/exmpl.html", 'a+'); 
    // Действия на чтение файла, сохранение измененного содержимого в  $textt
    ftruncate($fp, 0);
    $test2=fwrite($fp, $textt);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

В результате -

> Warning: ftruncate() [function.ftruncate]: Can't truncate this stream! in /home/a5235513/public_html/adm.php on line 131

Почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fp = fopen("http://bukvochka.webatu.com/Litra/Library/9/exmpl.html", 'a+');
```

Вы хотите очистить html страницу на чужом сервере ? :)

Сохраните файл на диск и будет вам счастье :)

Comment: Файл Php хранится на том же сервере.

Comment: это не важно. задайте локальный путь, без http

Comment: Спасибо огромное, исправил, получилось
:)

Comment: Если помогло - можете принять ответ, зеленая галочка.

Answer (score 1):

Все происходит из-за того, что вы неправильно открываете файл. Режим `"a+"` передвигает указатель файла на его конец, получается, отсекать нечего =). Попробуйте открыть файл в режиме `"r+"` и сделать все тоже самое, только не забудьте сместить указатель на место, с которого надо все отсечь! Используйте для этого функцию `"fseek()"`.

Comment: Спасибо, добавил, работает

Comment: Незачто =)